# How do I get a bot framework bot to send back a cell of a database if i type in a search parameter?

Tags: c#, database, t-sql, botframework, reader

I want to have a bot in the microsoft bot framework, c#, send back a favourite colour value of a person if you send the name. The data is stored in a database on azure. The connection is fine, the issue is as soon as i try to implement any reader object, it gives a code 500 error.

Example:

**user:** bill

**bot:** bill's favourite colour is red! Do you want to know anyone else's favourite colour?

The logic should therefore take the user input of bill, use it as an input parameter in a sql statement, then have the return value read and given back to the user via the bot.

My MessagesController.cs class is an unchanged from the bot template, I have tried to put all the logic in the RootDialog.cs which is below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ColourBot.Dialogs
{
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        string result10; 



        var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        cb.DataSource = "my_server.database.windows.net";
        cb.UserID = "user_id";
        cb.Password = "pass_word";
        cb.InitialCatalog = "ColourDB";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Colour FROM People Where Name=ed", connection);

            result10 = Submit_1_Tsql_SelectEmployees(connection);

            await context.PostAsync(

            $"The name you sent was {activity.Text}, their favourite colour is {result10}!");

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            string Build_1_Tsql_SelectEmployees()
            {
                return $@"SELECT
                                 Colour
                          FROM
                                 People
                          Where
                                  Name={activity.Text};";
            }
            string Submit_1_Tsql_SelectEmployees(SqlConnection conn)
            {
                string tsql = Build_1_Tsql_SelectEmployees();
                string nameString = "";

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(tsql, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var nameReturned = reader.GetName(0);
                            nameString = nameReturned.ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }
                return nameString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are probably better off using Entity Frameworks for a data access layer.  You can find an example using EF6 for simple CRUD functions in a [bot in this repo](https://github.com/JasonSowers/DatabaseBotExample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a bot application to test the code that you provided and debug the bot application with the [Bot Framework Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0), I find that the exception is caused by the missing single quotes around the value `Name={activity.Text}`.

You can modify the queryString to add the single quotes:

```
string Build_1_Tsql_SelectEmployees()
{
    return $@"SELECT Colour FROM People Where [Name]='{activity.Text}';";
}
```

Besides, to show user favourite colour, you can use the following code to return the data instaed of calling `reader.GetName(0)` to return column name.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //var nameReturned = reader.GetName(0);
        //nameString = nameReturned.ToString();
        nameString = reader[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

***Test result:***

[image]